# How to show the information of the selected row with DataTable React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datatable

I am trying that when opening the modal it only shows me the data of that line, for now I have only managed to show me all the data.
I am new to react and still not sure how to achieve it, I have read quite a lot of information but none that is adaptable to my project.
So in a nutshell try that when I click the button I have in the first list it opens a modal and inside that modal I have a table and it should show me only the data for the row I selected. Below I attach an image of the first table.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Button, Col, Form, Row } from "react-bootstrap";
import DataTable from "react-data-table-component";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { getByPurchaseEmail, getAllCities } from "../actions";
import { FaSearchLocation } from "react-icons/fa";
import Modal from "react-bootstrap/Modal";
import { BsFillBookmarkStarFill } from "react-icons/bs";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import ChangeRating from "./ChangeRating";
import StarRating from "./StarRating";
import moment from "moment";

function HomeUserPurchase() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const gState = useSelector((state) => state);
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const history = useHistory();
  const purchases = useSelector((state) => state.purchases);
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  const [avgRating, setAvgRating] = useState(0);
  const [selectedData, setSelectedData] = useState();

  const handleRating = (input) => {
    setAvgRating(input);
  };

  const changeCity = purchases;

  const nameCity = changeCity.map((e) => {
    return {
      idProducts: e.purchaseitems.map((e) => e.productId),
      id: e.id,
      maxDeliveryDate: e.maxDeliveryDate,
      totalPrice: e.totalPrice,
      cantidad: e.purchaseitems.reduce((a, e) => e.quantity + a, 0),
      producto: e.purchaseitems.map((e) => `${e.product.name}, `),
      arrivalCityId: gState.allCities.filter(
        (el) => parseInt(el.id) === parseInt(e.arrivalCityId)
      )[0].nombre,
    };
  });

  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

  **this is the second table.**
  const columnasRating = [
    {
      name: "Producto",
      selector: (row) => row.producto,
      sortable: true,
    },
  ];

  **this is the first table.**

  const columnas = [
    { name: "Nro de orden", selector: (row) => row.id, sortable: true },
    {
      name: "Producto",
      selector: (row) => row.producto,
      sortable: true,
    },
    {
      name: "Fecha de max de espera",
      selector: (row) => formatDate(row.maxDeliveryDate),
      sortable: true,
    },
    { name: "Ciudad", selector: (row) => row.arrivalCityId, sortable: true },
    {
      name: "Cantidad Total",
      selector: (row) => row.cantidad,
      sortable: true,
    },
    { name: "Precio total", selector: (row) => row.totalPrice, sortable: true },
    {
      button: true,
      cell: () => (
        <button style={{ display: "flex", fontSize: "20px" }}>
          <FaSearchLocation
            title="Encontrar viajero"
            style={{ marginRight: "15px", fontSize: "30px" }}
            onClick={(e) => editUsers(e)}
          />
          <BsFillBookmarkStarFill onClick={handleShow} />
        </button>
      ),
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="shadow-sm text-success mt-5 p-3 text-center rounded">
        Registros de compras
      </h1>
      <Row>
        <Col
          lg={12}
          md={12}
          sm={12}
          className="text-center p-5 m-auto shadow-sm rounded-lg"
        >
          <DataTable
            columns={columnas}
            data={nameCity}
            selectableRows
            title="Listado de compras"
          />
          <br />
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <Button onClick={(e) => history.goBack(e)}>Atras</Button>
      <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>
            Dejanos tu comentario sobre el producto que compraste
          </Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <DataTable
            columns={columnasRating}
            data={nameCity}
            title="Listado de compras"
          />
          {/* {nameCity.producto} */}
      
        
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="danger" onClick={handleClose}>
            Close
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}

export default HomeUserPurchase;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably suggest to instead store the `id` of the clicked row element in the `show` state and conditionally open the `Modal` on that and filter the table data within the modal.

Example:

```
function HomeUserPurchase() {
  ...

  const [show, setShow] = useState(null); // <-- initially null

  ...

  const handleClose = () => setShow(null); // <-- set null to close
  const handleShow = id => {
    // show new id or toggle modal closed
    setShow(showId => showId === id ? null : id);
  };

  ...

  **this is the first table.**
  const columnas = [
    ...
    {
      button: true,
      cell: (row) => (
        <button style={{ display: "flex", fontSize: "20px" }}>
          <FaSearchLocation
            title="Encontrar viajero"
            style={{ marginRight: "15px", fontSize: "30px" }}
            onClick={(e) => editUsers(e)}
          />
          <BsFillBookmarkStarFill onClick={() => handleShow(row.id)} /> // <-- pass element id
        </button>
      ),
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      ...
      <Modal
        show={show !== null} // <-- check show is non-null
        onHide={handleClose}
      >
        ...
        <Modal.Body>
          <DataTable
            columns={columnasRating}
            data={nameCity.filter(item => item.id === show)} // <-- filter data by id
            title="Listado de compras"
          />
        </Modal.Body>
        ...
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: @Kikegonzalez Oh, I see now. Votes on questions/answers is how content quality gets rated.